# imageview height in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I follow this guide to insert images in a gallery using grid view: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

I edited the imageadapter code as follow:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setId(R.id.img_gallery);

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private int[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1, R.drawable.itinerario1_1};
```

}

and this is img_gallery xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/img_gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

and this is the main layout:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" 
android:fadingEdge="none">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
/>
```

the problem is that when i tun the app, imageview has a lot of top and bottom padding. I also tried to set it to 0 in the xml but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the padding on runtime-

remove this line-

```
 imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

`imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);` in Base Adapter.

The xml file loads first, than the adapter.  That means that if you set the padding to 0 in your xml, they will still be overriden from your adapter class.  Try setting them to 0, or better yet, remove that line completely.  It should work.